# Using curl and php script to upload an image and text

Tags: php, image, curl, file-upload

I had been using the following script without any problems until today. I changed my linux's distro,and I don't know if it is related or not

```
     $full = realpath($newPath."/".$image);
     $data = array('name' => $name, 'pic' => '@'.$full.";type=image/jpeg");
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"));
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
     $contents = curl_exec($ch);
```

I am posting the info through a php's form, but I cannot submit the image due to that it isn't detected as an image, it is detected as "application/octet-stream"

How can I specify the content-type as an image and submit the text too?

P.D. I checked the similar questions asked before mine, I just found one with the exact purpouse and it hadn't any reply. I am not trying to download any image, I am trying to fill a form with several text fields and I should upload an image through the same form

Comment: No, it isn't a duplicate due to that my purpouse is different from that. I am trying to upload an image plus text and that guy is trying to download @MaxZoom

Comment: Which versions of PHP did you use? (old one and new one)

Comment: Uhm, I am using `PHP 7.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 20 2016 17:12:28) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies`, I know that I tested the script with php v5, may be that the cause of it doesn't work properly... not? @Dekel

Comment: I am having a similar issue, with nearly identical cURL options, after upgrading from PHP 5.4 to 7.0. The $_FILES superglobal is empty on the receiving end, with no error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I found the issue. You'll need to use the CurlFile() class, instead of the '@' . $file_name example.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Instead of

```
$postfields['file_contents'] = '@' . $filename;
```

You'll want to do this

```
$postfields['file_contents'] = new CurlFile($filename);
```

You can look at the docs for specifying mime type and name on the other end in the constructor, but that's the basic gist of it.

Best of luck!

Comment: I should add that this method should be used for PHP 5.5+ (including PHP 7)!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped me! :)